# Difference between randint and sample in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have tried to generate random codes and tried both

```
sample([0..9],x)
```

And

```
[randint(0,9) for i in range(x)]
```

When I first used sample I noticed that it doesn't generate numbers like "2222222" it generate more distributed numbers
While randint is more likely to generate numbers like "2222222".

What's the difference between both? and how I can choose the best method to generate random numbers for different cases?

Comment: `sample([0..9],x)` isn't valid Python code. Please could you edit to show the actual code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

1. The [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) method

Docs describe this function:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

In our case, the method takes `x` unique elements from the given range (this is enough for the uniqueness of result), nonetheless, the range contains 10 different numbers - therefore you haven't seen repeating elements.

Note: A good question would be what happens if we pass sample population that is smaller than the amount of different elements requested.
Well, in this case, an error will raise `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`.

2. The `randint` Loop

The `[randint(0,9) for i in range(x)]` generates random numbers, each iteration of the loop independently, so you witnessed repeating elements in the result.

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample(x, num)` always returns `num` unique element from a list x without repeating the output.

`random.randint(x, y)` returns a random number in the range x and y such that x < num < y.

You can read about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)